# Cannot read property 'aDataSort' of undefined for dynamic datatable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datatables, angular-datatables

all from this **http//jsfiddle.net/v6ruo7mj/1/** I created a dynamic data table, now I wanted to add the pagination, so I used jQuery data table and angular data table. but it was throwing **Cannot read property 'aDataSort' of undefined** and **Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null** errors. when I googled and I found it was due to empty **thead**. But I am binding that thead dynamically. there is a slight modification in my code. I added **thead** tag to the header. and **tbody** tag to the rows(data).

Comment: have no error/ all work fine

Comment: dimson can you, please add a fiddle or add sample code so that I can try it out..!!

Comment: try this pure angular plugin(and try not to use jQuery plugins) . its really simple https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/pagination

Answer (score 0):

with this plugin ( https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/pagination ) your html would be:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th ng-repeat="column in cols">{{column}}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr dir-paginate="row in rows | itemsPerPage: 3">
      <td ng-repeat="column in cols">{{row[column]}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <dir-pagination-controls></dir-pagination-controls>
</div>
```